# Could you weaponize an unarmed space shuttle?

Tags: spaceships

In the 26<sup>th</sup> century, space travel has become as cheap as air travel, and incredibly safe too. People whizz from solar system to solar system as if they were going from country to country, and the SPACE FORCE is the largest branch of the United Terran Federation Military.

One day, after receiving an SOS signal from the planet Kelstar, my main characters, about 5 people, load into a rescue ship and head to Kelstar. The shuttle they are in is not armed with any lasers, proton torpedos or anything, and is not traditionally armed.

#### Kelstar

They make it to Kelstar, where they are greeted by Eukary, a single-celled organism with near god like powers and abilities, who is quite abgrt at them for the whole Eye of Hades fiasco. Who wants revenge, and the 5 are about to be in for the fight of their lives. Their in an unarmed space shuttle, remember, so here is my question: Could you weaponize an unarmed spaceship?

#### Criteria

- No suicide attacks, as I would like these characters to stay alive
- Whatever you weaponize must be a feature common in most, of not all, starships
- Eukary is still vulnerable to attacks, as many of his powers are only offensive
- The Ship is almost exactly like a modern day Space Shuttle, but with the ability to go up to twice the speeds of the Saturn Vs, and is powered by a fusion reactor

Comment: Your ships are fictional and thus so are any features common to most or all of such ships. It is not possible to specify what items can be weaponized on board them as we do not know what is aboard them.

Comment: @TCAT117: It’s an Space Shuttle. It is 100% exactly like a modern day space shuttle, except with artificial gravity and a hologram projector

Comment: Does it posses an FTL drive? if so what kind? What is its power source? I'm trying to clarify enough info for an edit to occur so that you don't get down-voted or closed.

Comment: @TCAT117: Oh no, you don’t have to. I was going to edit it myself. No, it doesn’t have FTL, but it can go up to speeds of about two times the Apollo rockets. The power source is a Fusion reactor. Well, actually two, a main one and a backup.

Comment: Alright, I think I can take a crack at this now.

Comment: @TCAT117: Alright how long do you think it’ll take. Hopefully I’ll have time for a quick YouTube video lol

Comment: Yeah... 100% exactly like a modern day space shuttle, except it's still in service, powered by fusion, twice as fast, can control gravity, and can manipulate radiation in the visual spectrum. (asking this question about an actual STS would've been pretty cool)

Comment: *"Twice the speed of the Apollo rockets"* The fastest of these was 11.08 km/s.  At twice this speed it would take about 13585 *years* to reach the nearest star.  At the speed of light it would take about 4 years.  So no one is going to be whizzing between solar systems.  That's why people keep asking about FTL in your scenario.

Comment: @StephenG: You misunderstood. The craft they are in is like a rescue craft is isn’t outitted with full FTL engines. Ships have the ability to go FTL

Comment: @Mazura: Really it would?

Comment: First thought was a kinetic kill vehicle, but you said no suicides. Next was somehow using the RCS, depressurizing certain parts; shooting junk out of an airlock, things you might do on an EVA, or using the robotic arm. Basically *Armageddon*, but they didn't bring a minigun or nukes, and they didn't know they'd have to fight bacteria once they got there.

Comment: @Mazura: expand on it. Make an answer!!!

Comment: I am absolutely convinced there are people on this site who don't understand what "primarily opinion-based" means.  Considering that all you have to work with is the shuttle, its contents, and its crew, the answer will NOT be POB.

Comment: Well space travel wouldn't be safe if the ship they are in is almost exactly like the Space Shuttle. The space shuttle blew up, twice (out of 135 missions), and required extensive maintenance between flights. Also if it goes twice as fast as the Saturn V that's still very slow for interstellar or even interplanetary travel. ...You can't make it like the Space Shuttle and have it be viable in a technologically advanced civilization. It'd be like the Wright Flyer trying to take out a drone swarm * a million.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Your Fusion Engines ARE Weapons**

Does this being's godlike powers involve the ability to withstand apocalyptic amounts of Neutron and Gamma radiation? Because anything within a few hundred to a few thousand kilometers of the rear of this vessel are being positively blasted with it. A fusion engine works by ejecting a very hot stream of fusion plasma out the back, and dependent upon the method used to achieve this fusion your shuttle's exhaust is going to range from hot to "oh my god! we just torched that settlement."

Your heroes are plucky and have an excellent engineer who may or may not be Scottish. He recalibrates/reconfigures your ship's engines to fire an intense beam of radioactive fusion plasma at much higher intensity and much more focused that that which would normally be used to propel the vessel. It's a risky, NEAR suicidal maneuver as at any moment the containment could fail and incinerate the vessel, and the radiation levels experienced in the cockpit may or may not cause sterility and possible rad-sickness/death but who cares about having kids or losing a few teeth and or fingernails? we have space monsters to incinerate!

[image]

Your plucky heroes feign being adrift, disabled and out of power in order to draw the monster as close as possible for maximum effect. Then they hit him with a beam of radioactive ravening death several times hotter than the sun once their rotation has "aimed" this makeshift weapon at the beast.

Note: there is a lot of hand-waving involved here, but the basic principle is sound. Fusion engines powerful enough for star-travel are pretty dangerous to be behind/around all on their own.

Comment: Oh cool answer TCAT. Like the fact that theirs danger and risks involved, that makes it more exciting. Unless someone else somehow tops this, I’m using your idea

Comment: For an added bit of realism the acceleration experienced would be pretty dangerous too. It would be a pretty high G affair.

Comment: No, not with their energized Talotonium force field anti G generators

Comment: I also thought about the same, but slightly different approach. Assuming that's a planetary target. Glide with engines turned off, when you are just above target use the engines to provide thrust to slow down almost to zero. Consequently, while being over target float using your engines. (acceleration of engines should cancel out planet gravitation, assuming that vehicle is capable of vertical take off such manoeuvre would not even require full power) Assuming that engine is designed for long periods of activity, then you can slowly scorch some area.

Answer (score 4):

"We are coming into the system awfully fast, Captain!"

"Steady as she goes, Ensign. I'll say when."

"Captain, sensors have detected a... thing... on the bow of our ship!"

"Yes, that would be my coffee mug. I left it sitting on the hood when we pulled out of that last station."

"Well, it's pinned firm against the bow right now, but as soon as we start braking..."

"Brakes now, Ensign!"

"Yes, sir! All stop. But your mug, sir, it's..."

"Yes, Ensign, it is flying away from us at ludicrous speed because it wasn't strapped down. Indeed. And The Entity is about to have hot coffee spilled at it at very high speed!"

"Um... sir, I hate to say this but... even at that speed, the mug won't do much damage. And the coffee won't be hot... it's been sitting outside in space."

"Did I forget to mention that I like to use cubes of radioactive unobtanium to keep my coffee warm?"

"What?! That's insane. The cancer...!"

"We cured cancer last episode, remember? And we were going faster than light to zip between star systems... do the math on kinetic energy! The ceramic is enough for most enemies! But with an atomic weight of 75,567, a coffee mug of unobtainum..."

"... becomes an incredibly powerful, tiny-enough-to-be-hard-to-detect on radar bullet! Sir, that's brilliant."

"Thank you. Now if you'll kindly turn on the view monitor, I believe we have 15 seconds until our one-cell friend experiences a mind-blowing kaboom!"

Comment: That's the spirit!  Creative fiction as an answer!  Woot!

Comment: I think you should become acquainted with zee captain of the "romantically apocalyptic" series. He solves all of his problems by scalding it with hot tea from a sentient never-ending coffee mug (nano-tech and strong AI, it gets..... weird.) you should look it up. Its a free web-comic.

Comment: I know zee captain of captainia! Zee is great inspiration to all space captains everywhere, including those in space! @TCAT117

Comment: what about the ones who only exist subjectivley?

Comment: Are we not all subjects of the Good Directorate? Even those who object to the directorate (i.e. exist objectively) are subject to it. Thus objectivity is merely a subset of subjectivity. You must've been snipped between the ears to not think of zees things!

Answer (score 1):

Single-cell organism?
No matter how powerful, just make sure that your shuttle has at least a pocket biolaboratory and create a heck of a virus to send with your best regards

Comment: KSP mission contract accepted: Maintain stable low orbit; inclination 0. Research "HECK virus". Deploy 'mystery goo' atomizer for 48h. Return safety to Kelstar.